# Change column data type in all tables

Tags: mysql, alter

I want alter all table that has column with date type `DateTime` or `Date`.

With this query can convert datetime to char(19) and date to chat(10) now how can find all column with date type datetime or date and convert it in all table?

```
ALTER TABLE `llx_payment_salary`
    CHANGE COLUMN `datec` `datec` CHAR(19) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `tms`,
    CHANGE COLUMN `datep` `datep` CHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `fk_user`,
```

Comment: I think you might need some dynamic SQL for that (I didn't downvote you).

Answer (score 0):

try this to find them, but keep in mind that you generally shouldn't change system tables, only your created tables:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE column_type LIKE 'date%'
```